# How to copy Outlook 2003 recipients to clipboard verbatim

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

So I have a message in Outlook with about 30 recipients. I need to respond to those recipients from my Gmail account. No problem, right? I'll just cut and paste from Outlook to Gmail.

In Outlook:

```
To: Freddy Oo <foo@example.com>; Barbara Ar <bar@example.com>; 
    Basil Az <baz@example.com>; Quinn Ux <quux@example.com>
```

Copied and pasted into other programs:

```
Freddy Oo; Barbara Ar; Basil Az; Quinn Ux
```

The command copied just the names and not the email addresses to the clipboard.

How can I do a verbatim copy? I tried the Scraper program which is supposed to copy text from dialog boxes or other Windows, and it failed.

I even tried cut+paste / drag and drop from Outlook to Word and Excel. I got the same result, the email addresses aren't put onto the clipboard. Grrrrr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the email in question, under menu option 'View' select 'Options'. You will see Internet headers at the bottom and all the gory details including exact names and addresses are there under the 'To:' section.

Answer (score 0):

And what if you copy into Notepad ?
From my Outlook 2010, copy/paste of names and email addresses works fine (even to my Excel 2010 unlike posted in [Copying email addresses from To: field to excel](https://superuser.com/questions/282028/copying-email-addresses-from-to-field-to-excel/282174#282174)).