# Outlook 2003: how to forward messages and not lose the sender/recipient email addresses

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

This is a follow-up for [my other question about Outlook 2003](https://superuser.com/questions/70149/how-to-copy-outlook-2003-recipients-to-clipboard-verbatim).

**How do I get Outlook 2003 to forward messages and include the email addresses instead of hiding them?**

Let's say I have the following email message in Outlook (the `<>` represents a hidden email address that Outlook knows but doesn't display):

```
From: Freddy Oo <foo@example.com>
Sent: Thu 12/3/2009 7:08 PM
To: Jason S <js@example.com>; Barbara Ar <bar@example.com>
Cc: Basil Az <baz@example.com>; Quinn Ux <quux@example.com>
Subject: Something

I have something to say but I forgot what it was. Sorry.
```

When I go to forward this message, it looks like this: (Outlook has all the information, but the program is just boneheaded.)

```
From: Jason S <js@example.com>
To:
Subject: FW: Something
----------

From: Freddy Oo
Sent: Thu 12/3/2009 7:08 PM
To: Jason S; Barbara Ar
Cc: Basil Az; Quinn Ux
Subject: Something

I have something to say but I forgot what it was. Sorry.
```

It just shows the display name and I lose the email addresses, which really sucks. How can I fix this?

**clarification**: I need to forward an email message to someone. (it may even be to myself to another account) Often it has several recipients. When I forward from Outlook, I lose the actual email address, it just keeps the display name (see above). Therefore the recipients of my forwarded email address do not have access to those email addresses. I could fix it up manually, but that is extremely time-consuming and a continued annoyance.

What I want is to forward my message and have it look like this:

```
From: Jason S <js@example.com>
To:
Subject: FW: Something
----------

From: Freddy Oo <foo@example.com>
Sent: Thu 12/3/2009 7:08 PM
To: Jason S <js@example.com>; Barbara Ar <bar@example.com>
Cc: Basil Az <baz@example.com>; Quinn Ux <quux@example.com>
Subject: Something

I have something to say but I forgot what it was. Sorry.
```

Comment: Good question! Maybe you should re-write your question to be much easier to understand. You have an up-vote for your question, I also want to find the answer for this.

Comment: try CTRL+ALT+F, it will forward the mail as attachment, where the email addresses would be preserved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also not the smoothest answer, but you can open up the email, and click on the Options... button (or if it's not added to your toolbar, it's menu item View->Options...). You then can see the full internet headers, including all the full email addresses. Copy and paste whatever portion of that text you want into your reply.

[image: Outlook Message Options dialog screenshot]

Not elegant, but works.

Comment: not bad, looks like at least something that preserves the original information. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is an option in Outlook 2003, but in 2007 you can use `Actions -> Forward as Attachment` to forward the original email with *all* header information intact.

It's a little less convenient for the recipient though, as they now have a .msg file to open instead of reading the forwarded email inline with your message.

Comment: Right, this will preserve the original email with all header info intact, but still doesn't answer the question, since not all users will reply/fwd including the original email as attachment.

Maybe there is no other way to do this...

Comment: The original question states "what *I* want is to forward *my* message..." (emphasis added), so I think this is a potential answer for him.

That said, I came to this question in your boat, looking for a way to force everyone's Outlook to always include email addresses when forwarding.  I still haven't found a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is not possible.

Refer to [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/outlook/thread/7196cf81-7822-48bd-8ac5-96ae46566255)

> There is no way to change that. Internal addresses simply do not show as (in general) they are not needed as addressing the email by name would suffice since Exchange resolves them.
>
> External addresses will show and do get printed. If an email gets forwarded, the external email address is also placed above the quoted text. Are you saying that this isn't the case for you?
>
> If the person forwarding the message to you was internal for the original sender and they were using Exchange, then the original addresses wouldn't get quoted either of course.
>
> If the order is generated by a form, you could opt to have the email address also be added to the message body.

Comment: <rant>This is one of the small issues that make IT shops find new email server software.  So aggravating.</rant>

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer for this: right click the display name and select **Who is...** 
If the person is in our address book on in the LDAP directory or domain, you will be able to see the email address.

Comment: thanks, I already know how to do that. The point of computers is that they are supposed to make complex tasks a trivial matter, and they are *not* supposed to make trivial tasks a complex matter.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the format to Text format, and it will preserve the addresses of all senders and recipients of the previous email in the email string you are replying to or forwarding.

That is the only way I know of besides attaching it, and it is still a bit of a workaround, but more convenient because it can easily be set up in the options, though inconvenient if you have an image in your signature or a screenshot or picture you are trying to email (though these can easily be attached to a text email, of course).