# Forwarding / Redirecting emails keeps stripping out the original senders email address

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

We have an enquires@company.com email account.  This account has an auto forwarding rule (I've tried auto redirect rule too), which will forward emails to other user accounts, i.e. user1@company.com and user2.company.com

The problem is what when these emails are forwarded to user1 and user2, the original senders email address is stripped out for some reason, so it only shows the senders name.  However, the senders email address can be seen when looking directly as the enquires email account.

For example

someone@gmail.com sends an email to enquiries@company.com.  All good so far and enquiries@company.com gets an email showing something like this:

from: someone [someone@gmail.com]

when this email is forwarded from the enquiries@company.com account to user1 and user2@company.com, those 2 users get emails without the email address, i.e.

from: someone

instead of

from: someone [someone@gmail.com]

Why is this happening, and how do I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "forward message as an attachment". 
`Actions -> Forward as Attachment` to forward the original email with all header information intact; thus you can retrieve the sender's and receiver's email addresses in the original email. Thanks to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/79945/outlook-2003-how-to-forward-messages-and-not-lose-the-sender-recipient-email-ad).

[image]