# How to make Outlook always show the full email id of a forwarded mail

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Am currently using Outlook 2013.

Several times, when a mail is forwarded to me, i only see the First/Last name of the person in the forwarded mail, not the email id. Is there a way to make Outlook always display the  email id.

I get these mails from people, who are also using Outlook but different versions.

One solution which we have to resort to, is to attach the mail, rather than forward, that way it retains the email address, but this is cumbersome, and I cannot ask everyone to do this.

This is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/79945/outlook-2003-how-to-forward-messages-and-not-lose-the-sender-recipient-email-ad) question, but the answer selected does not work for me.