# Copying email addresses from To: field to excel

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to copy Outlook 2003 recipients to clipboard verbatim](https://superuser.com/questions/70149/how-to-copy-outlook-2003-recipients-to-clipboard-verbatim)

How can I copy email addresses from Outlook's To: field to excel? When using copy + paste I get only names (Surname Frontname) without addresses. I can copy addresses one by one, but I need to copy dozens of addresses so it would be easier to do it in bigger groups. Unfortunately the addresses are not in Outlook's Contacts.

Comment: After I read the answers to http://superuser.com/questions/70149/how-to-copy-outlook-2003-recipients-to-clipboard-verbatim the problem still exist, maybe because of Office 2007 instead of Office 2010?

Comment: It should work with Distribution List. First copy adresses from to: field, then make new Distribution List, then Select members, paste addresses to members field and save. Still it don't work with all the adresses, don't know why.